# Angular display message if data is not found after input

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to display a message when Data is not found from our API after the user input its number and the button is clicked.

Here is my html

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-input placeholder="Number" [(ngModel)]="myNum"></ion-input>
      <ion-button (click)="onClick()">UPDATE</ion-button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>



  <ng-container *ngIf="!error; else errorContent">

    <p *ngFor="let order of orders; let i=index;">
      <ion-item *ngIf="i==0">Number : <b>{{ order?.Number }}</b></ion-item>


    </p>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #errorContent>
    <p>
      <span style="color: red;">{{error}}</span>
    </p>
  </ng-template>
<ng-template ngif="blank">
    Document Number not Found
  </ng-template>
</ion-content>
```

Here.s my page.ts which is for displaying the Data and for when the button is clicked. I tried to add a property (this.blank) for null, 0 and length = 0 for API.

```
    ionViewWillEnter() {
  // Load the data
  this.prepareDataRequest().subscribe( //comment this if you will use Api Url
  //this.dataService.getRemoteData(this.myNum).subscribe( //comment this if you will use local data
    (data:any) => {
      // Takes data into in single Array and print 
      this.actualOrders = data.output.OrderTracking;
      this.orders = data.output.OrderTracking;
      this.blank = data.output.OrderTracking == null |data.output.OrderTracking === 0 || data.output.OrderTracking.length === 0;
    },
    err => {
      // Set the error information to display in the template
      this.error = `An error occurred, the data could not be retrieved: Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`;
    }
  );
}

onClick () {

    this.dataService.getRemoteData(this.myNum).subscribe( //comment this if you will use local data
      (data:any) => {
        // Takes data into in single Array and print 
        this.orders = data.output.Result.OrderTracking;
        console.log("Remote Data:");
        console.log(data);

    this.blank = data.output.OrderTracking == null |data.output.OrderTrackin === 0 || data.output.OrderTracking.length === 0;
      },
      err => {
        // Set the error information to display in the template
        this.error = `An error occurred, the data could not be retrieved: Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: what is your problem? Are you receiving an error from your API?

Comment: I just want to display a message when a number is not existing/found from our API

Comment: The code you posted seems to work perfectly. I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: Just like I said, I want to display an error message when the number is not existing/not found from our API

Comment: I suppose you mean when your API returns empty values, don't you?

Comment: When the user input a number which is not existing from the API, it will display the error message

Comment: You need to evaluate that case and show a message related to it inside the subscribe statement. Your API response needs to return something to indicate this case.

Comment: I updated my code, can you kindly check? its still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you made a typo with `ngIf` clause on the HTML.

```html
<ng-template ngif="blank"> <!-- <<<-- *ngIf -->
    Document Number not Found
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Is this your full HTM? There is a `</ion-list>` closing tag, but it is not open (line 5). And there is a `</ion-content>` closing tag, not open (last line). Maybe you should try with a simple `<p *ngIf="blank">` instead of  `<ng-template *ngIf="blank">`, just to check that it works.

Comment: Ahh Yes, its not my full html. tried it also with <p> tag, still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to test it under `<ng-container *ngIf="!error; else errorContent">` (with a `<p>` I whould say, or similar), instead of in `<ng-template>` ?? Maybe the template tag is expecting some form of ID to be triggered to be shown.

Comment: No luck either :(

Comment: Have you tried with the negative clause? Like `*ngIf=" !blank "`, just to check that the container you want to show, actually displays itself.

Comment: It did display, but it only must display when the UPDATE button is clicked

Comment: Ok, but it is safe to check if it is a framework error or not. You could try accessing params in an array style, instead of JSON approach, like `this.blank = data["output"]["OrderTracking"] == null | (data["output"]["OrderTrackin"] == 0 || data["output"]["OrderTracking"].length == 0);`. Sometimes Angular does not recognise JSON aproach if, like in this case, it is `null`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214258/discussion-between-vista-and-sergio).

Comment: Ohh i Think it works, under constructor I need to se this.blank = false; instead of true